# Hide an html element if a css var is greater than some value

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'd like hide an element if a css var is greater than zero. I can get the inverse case to work:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px soild black;
}

.item {
  opacity: max(calc( var(--ind)*1), 0);
/* or clamp(var(--ind), 0 , 1);*/
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 0;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 1;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 2;background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 3;background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 4;background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

However, I'd like to have the above example show only the red sqare.
Can anyone see how to do this (in pure css)?

Comment: What about ` opacity: max(calc( 1 - var(--ind)*1), 0);` ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser wonderful! Why not post as an answer and I'll +1/accept

Comment: `opacity: min(calc( 1 - var(--ind)*1), 1);` also works :-)

Comment: The `*1` is redundant too (originally came from experimenting)

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px soild black;
}

.item {
  opacity: min(calc( 1 - var(--ind)), 1);
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 0;background-color:red;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 1;background-color:orange;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 2;background-color:yellow;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 3;background-color:green;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--ind: 4;background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
```